# Missing Script "vite" when run vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm

I want to build a vue project.I use `npm init vue@latest` to init my project.Then I run `npm install` to install packages.But When I run `npm run dev`.I met an error.
[image]

Then I run `npm run vite preview --port 4173`.But It shows that I don't have a vite Script.Then I run `npm install vite`.It does not work.Please help me.Thanks a lot.
[image]

this is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "weathercheck",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.38",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "vite": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first error indicates that you are using an older version of `node.js`. I recently bumped into that. Check [this thread](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9113) for more details

As per vite's site:

> Compatibility Note
>
> Vite requires Node.js version 14.18+, 16+. However, some templates require a higher Node.js version to work, please upgrade if your package manager warns about it.

The second error is quite correct though. There is no such script called `vite` in your `package.json`.

try `npm run preview`.